# python 2.7 trying to assign a string slice to a string

Tags: python-2.7

I am simply trying to assign a slice of a `string` to another `string` so it is easy to manipulate in the script. I can print the slice: 
`print full_path[startIndex:endIndex+5];`

but assigning it to another string renders this exception in eclipse: module not in the pythonpath

```
modulePath=full_path[startIndex:endIndex+5];
```

I thought `full_path[startIndex:endIndex+5]` returns string, but I am not sure.

Am I not declaring the string correctly, is it not the string that being returned?

Please help.
Thank you.
Vicki

Comment: And you're getting your error on that line? Or does it come later when you are trying to use the result and import the module it specifies? I ask because that error is not related (at least as far as I can tell) to that particular line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here does not come from how you slice the string, which looks fine. The exception that is thrown indicates that the module you're trying to import is not found by python. To avoid that kind of problem, try to store all you scripts in a specific location and add this location to the environment variable "PYTHONPATH".

If you are on windows, check this thread out:

[How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

Comment: Thank you for your replies. My problem had nothing to do with the string assignment or un-imported modules. It was the formatting. I am used to java style of not paying attention to formatting and getting very relevant error messages on compile. I found that I had to retype my python script in eclipse to get rid of the errors :)